# FB.api is always undefined?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying really hard to learn how to do this but I keep running into problems.

FB.ui works for posting but every time I use FB.api it comes up as undefined and I get a random picture. What am I doing wrong?

```
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : 'numbers', // App ID
            channelUrl : '/channel.php', // Channel File
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
          });
          FB.api('/me', function(user) {
            if (user) {
              var image = document.getElementById('image');
              image.src = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + user.id + '/picture';
              var name = document.getElementById('name');
              name.innerHTML = user.name
            }
          });
        };
        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function(d, s, id){
           var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
           if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
           fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
         }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
      </script>
      <div align="center">
        <img id="image"/>
        <div id="name"></div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call FB.login before making the API call. I guess, thats what you are missing.